# How come my value gets reset to 0 when I change screen if I am using async storage?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using a stack Navigator, my main screen is tracker.js, and a second screen macros.js
On macros.js I can add nutritional macros (calories, Fats, Carbs, Protein) manually, and add it to my UsedDailyCalories. However when I go back to my tracker.js, which is automatically got 0 calories and I return to macros.js, the value goes back down to 0. And I am not sure why async storage is not working. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Modal,
  Animated,
} from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";

export default class Macros extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "My Macros",
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getData();


    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: null,
      totalCalsSet: 0,
      showModal: false,
      showModal2: false,
      UsedDailyCalories: 0,
      UsedDailyFat: +this.props.navigation.getParam("totalFat", "nothing sent"),
      UsedDailyCarbs: 0,
      UsedDailyProtein: 0,
      CalsFatInput: 0,
      CalsProteinInput: 0,
      CalsCarbsInput: 0,
      CaloriePercentage: 0,
    };

    let calsTakenFromTracker = this.props.navigation.getParam("totalCal", "nothing sent");
    this.state.UsedDailyCalories += calsTakenFromTracker;

  }



  setMacroGoalModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true,
    });
  };

  AddMacrosModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      showModal2: true,
    });
  };

  addMacrosManually = (ProteinInput, FatInput, CarbsInput) => {

    let CalsProteinInput = ProteinInput * 4;
    let CalsFatInput = FatInput * 9;
    let CalsCarbsInput = CarbsInput * 4;

    let CalsCalorieInput = CalsCarbsInput + CalsFatInput + CalsProteinInput;
    let withAddedCalories = this.state.UsedDailyCalories + CalsCalorieInput;
    this.setState({
      UsedDailyCalories :withAddedCalories,
      UsedDailyFat: +FatInput,
      UsedDailyCarbs: +CarbsInput,
      UsedDailyProtein: +ProteinInput,
      showModal2: false,
    });
    console.log(this.state.UsedDailyCalories);


    const firstPair = ["UsedTotalCalories", JSON.stringify(this.state.UsedDailyCalories)];
    const secondPair = ["UsedTotalCarbs", JSON.stringify(this.state.UsedDailyCarbs)];
    const thirdPair = ["UsedTotalProtein", JSON.stringify(this.state.UsedDailyProtein)];
    const fourthPair = ["UsedTotalFat", JSON.stringify(this.state.UsedDailyFat)];

    try {
      this.setState({});
      var usedValues = [firstPair, secondPair, thirdPair, fourthPair];
      AsyncStorage.setItem("DATA_KEY", JSON.stringify(usedValues))


    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

  };

  setMacros = async (ProteinInput, FatInput, CarbsInput) => {
    let CalsProteinInput = ProteinInput * 4;
    let CalsFatInput = FatInput * 9;
    let CalsCarbsInput = CarbsInput * 4;
    let totalCalsSet = CalsCarbsInput + CalsFatInput + CalsProteinInput;

    let CaloriePercentage = (totalCalsSet / 2400) * 100;
    this.setState({
      totalCalsSet: totalCalsSet,
      CalsProteinInput: ProteinInput,
      CalsFatInput: FatInput,
      CalsCarbsInput: CalsCarbsInput,
      showModal: false,
      CaloriePercentage: CaloriePercentage,
    });
    console.log(totalCalsSet);


    const firstPair = ["totalCalsSet", JSON.stringify(this.state.totalCalories)];
    const secondPair = ["totalCarbsSet", JSON.stringify(CarbsInput)];
    const thirdPair = ["totalProteinSet", JSON.stringify(ProteinInput)];
    const fourthPair = ["totalFatSet", JSON.stringify(FatInput)];

    try {
      this.setState({});
      var setValues = [firstPair, secondPair, thirdPair, fourthPair];
      AsyncStorage.setItem("DATA_KEY", JSON.stringify(setValues))


    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

  };



  getData = async () => {

    try {
      AsyncStorage.multiGet(["key1", "key2"]).then(response => {
      })

    } catch(e) {
      // read error
    }
  };




  render() {


    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    let CaloriePercentage = this.state.CaloriePercentage + "%";

    return (
      //styling for navigation container
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.topStyle}>
          <Text>{this.state.UsedDailyCalories} </Text>
          <Text>{this.state.UsedDailyCarbs} </Text>

          <View style={styles.setMacros}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setMacroGoalModal()}>
              <Text> Set Daily Macro Goal </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.setMacros} onPress={() => this.AddMacrosModal()}>
            <Text> add Daily Macro Goal </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.viewOfMacros}>
            <Text>Cals: {this.state.totalCalsSet}</Text>
            <Text>{Math.floor(this.state.CaloriePercentage)}%</Text>

            <View style={styles.progressBar}>
              <Animated.View
                style={
                  ([StyleSheet.absoluteFill],
                  { backgroundColor: "#8BED4F", width: CaloriePercentage })
                }
              />
            </View>
            <Text>Fat: {this.state.CalsFatInput}</Text>
            <Text>Carbs: {this.state.CalsCarbsInput}</Text>
            <Text>Protein: {this.state.CalsProteinInput}</Text>
          </View>

          <View>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous, so if you call `setState` and then immediately try to access its values they will be old.

You can either use the callback available as the second argument to `setState`, [check that out here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)  or you can just use the values you used to set your state and pass those to your file system for storage.

Let me know if that doesn't make enough sense.

Comment: Hi, i am not sure if the link is correct please confirm. And surely Async storage allows the user to maintain state when switching screens?

Comment: thanks, that's strange that the link was the wrong one, I'll update it. And async storage should work, but if you are setting it with the old data it won't have the new data in the next screen.